# How can other parties track the inflows, outflows, and reserves of exchanges?

Tags: exchanges, withdrawal, deposit, chainanalysis

I see that there are a few sites that provide analytics for the reserves that exchanges are holding as well as inflows and outflows (e.g.
https://www.tokenanalyst.io/dashboard).

How are these companies able to track this information?  Are the addresses of major exchanges publicly known?  Do the exchanges publish or offer this data?

Answer (score 4):

Most exchanges aren't publishing this data, some are even trying to hide as much of it as possible, using separate wallets and trying to be smart about change progression.
A lot of the analytic companies are using repositories (examples:[1](https://www.walletexplorer.com/), [2](https://oxt.me/)) of publicly known addresses to find out the wallet ownership.

But this isn't the optimal solution when it comes to analytics, some blockchain analytic companies are actually applying as customers of these exchanges and trying to get on-chain activity, main addresses (so-called hotwallets) and marking wallets through [common input clustering](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Privacy#Common-input-ownership_heuristic).

Answer (score -2):

just calculate amount of btc hold on exchange using exchange's api. u dont need any wallets for that

Comment: Could you give an example which data exchanges offer that you can use to calculate their reserves? The order book doesn't necessarily hold all their reserves. Perhaps you could elaborate a bit more what you mean.